# Remove trailing slash from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My address of website is

`https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new/`
This website is in subfolder - new

I want address to be

`https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new`

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
    # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /new/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

what to do?

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file in the document root already or in the `/new` subdirectory?

Comment: this htaccess above is in subdirectory /new

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?

It gets a little messy, as Apache *requires* the trailing slash on the directory in order to evaluate the `DirectoryIndex` etc. By disabling the trailing slash, we must handle this situation manually with mod_rewrite.

Try the following:

**1)** *Move* the `/new/.htaccess` file into the root at `/.htaccess`. This takes the `.htaccess` out of WordPress, so WP can no longer maintain this file (not necessarily a bad thing).

**2)** Change the `/.htaccess` file to read:

```
# Prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash to directories (with a 301 redirect)
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new

# Allow mod_rewrite to match directories that do not have a trailing slash (when DirecrorySlash Off)
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Rewrite directory without trailing slash directly to the front-controller
RewriteRule ^new$ index.php [L]

# Standard front-controller
RewriteRule ^new/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^new/. index.php [L]
```